# How to rebuild a GUID partition table in a APFS file system SSD?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, ssd, mount, apfs

I looked at other answers for similar questions but not one works for me (maybe because the APFS).

I have an external 1 TB SSD with two APFS volumes. Somebody plug my hard drive into a Windows 10 PC and after that did not work any more. When I connect the device to my MacBook it doesn't get mounted or even recognized by Disk Utility...

I been trying using `diskutil` like this:

```
 MacBook-Pro-de-Ying:~ yingyang$ diskutil list



     /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:      TYPE NAME                   SIZE                IDENTIFIER
           0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
           1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         445.0 GB   disk0s2
       3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                55.1 GB    disk0s3

    /dev/disk1 (synthesized):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +445.0 GB   disk1
                                     Physical Store disk0s2
       1:                APFS Volume macOS                   206.0 GB   disk1s1
       2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 109.6 MB   disk1s2
       3:                APFS Volume Recovery                2.1 GB     disk1s3
       4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4

    MacBook-Pro-de-Ying:~ yingyang$ diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk1

    Started file system verification on disk1
    Verifying storage system
    Using live mode
    Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l /dev/disk0s2
    Checking the container superblock
    Checking the EFI jumpstart record
    Checking the space manager
    Checking the space manager free queue trees
    Checking the object map
    Checking volume
    Checking the APFS volume superblock
    The volume macOS was formatted by diskmanagementd (945.200.129) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.200.129)
    Checking the object map
    Checking the snapshot metadata tree
    Checking the snapshot metadata
    Checking snapshot 1 of 13
    Checking snapshot 2 of 13
    Checking snapshot 3 of 13
    Checking snapshot 4 of 13
    Checking snapshot 5 of 13
    Checking snapshot 6 of 13
    Checking snapshot 7 of 13
    Checking snapshot 8 of 13
    Checking snapshot 9 of 13
    Checking snapshot 10 of 13
    Checking snapshot 11 of 13
    Checking snapshot 12 of 13
    Checking snapshot 13 of 13
    Checking the extent ref tree
    Checking the fsroot tree
    Checking volume
    Checking the APFS volume superblock
    The volume Preboot was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.200.129)
    Checking the object map
    Checking the snapshot metadata tree
    Checking the snapshot metadata
    Checking the extent ref tree
    Checking the fsroot tree
    Checking volume
    Checking the APFS volume superblock
    The volume Recovery was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.200.129)
    Checking the object map
    Checking the snapshot metadata tree
    Checking the snapshot metadata
    Checking the extent ref tree
    Checking the fsroot tree
    Checking volume
    Checking the APFS volume superblock
    The volume VM was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.200.129)
    Checking the object map
    Checking the snapshot metadata tree
    Checking the snapshot metadata
    Checking the extent ref tree
    Checking the fsroot tree
    Verifying allocated space
    warning: Overallocation Detected on Main device: (60262568+1) bitmap address (115f8)
    warning: Overallocation Detected on Main device: (65950894+1) bitmap address (10508)
    warning: Overallocation Detected on Main device: (66409253+1) bitmap address (10517)
    Performing deferred repairs
    The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK
    Storage system check exit code is 0
    Finished file system verification on disk1

    MacBook-Pro-de-Ying:~ yingyang$ diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk1
    Unable to repair this whole disk: A GUID Partition Table (GPT) partitioning scheme is required (-69773)

    MacBook-Pro-de-Ying:~ yingyang$ diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk1s1
    Error starting file system repair for disk1s1 macOS: Unable to unmount volume for repair (-69673)

MacBook-Pro-de-Ying:~ yingyang$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1
Unmount of disk1 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted

    MacBook-Pro-de-Ying:~ yingyang$ diskutil umount /dev/disk1s1
    Volume macOS on disk1s1 failed to unmount: dissented by PID 0 (kernel)
```

I have no idea how to continue.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the 3rd party disk utilities (like DiskWarrior) work with APFS yet either. It really was released to market a little too quickly. Also it's intended for SSD use, not HDD use. All that said, I think you're going to be stuck restoring from backups at this point. There's just no tools for APFS

Comment: @l008com Yes, SSD ;-) also I know that third-party apps don´t work. But must be some way to do it with command line.

Comment: Update: If I try the fsck command that's what happened:
 
$ fsck_apfs /dev/disk1
error: container /dev/rdisk1 is mounted with write access.
$ fsck -y -l 1
error: container /dev/rdisk1 is mounted with write access.

Comment: Your internal drive is `disk0`. The contents of the APFS container stored in `disk0` is shown as `disk1`. None of the commands you entered have been applied to the 1TB SSD. The external drive is not even appearing in the output from the commands you have entered.

Comment: @DavidAnderson any solution?

Comment: Well, you have not posted any useful information. So far, I know there is a 1 TB SSD that does not appear in the output from `diskutil list`. Looks like some type of hardware failure.